# Set Salable Quantity to No manage stock

Tags: magento2, salable

How can i set the salable quantity value as No manage Stock in magento 2.3.3
https://prnt.sc/xcehjd

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for all products using a script file from the root then you can use this.

Create a **script.php** file in your Magento root directory

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();

foreach ($collection as $key => $product) {
        $product->setStockData(array( 
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                    'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                    'qty' => 100,
                    'manage_stock' => 0,
                    'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 0
                )); 
        $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Hi, how can I set salable quantity to match quantity per source or keep it in stock?